# Why do I need extern?

Tags: c++, extern

I am getting GL function in my code using wglGetProcAddress. The author of the guide (https://sites.google.com/site/opengltutorialsbyaks/introduction-to-opengl-3-2---tutorial-01) says that I need to define functions like this:

```
extern PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC glCreateProgram;
```

Using extern keyword. But I tried without it and it works (compilation is successfully complete and the program successfully uses the function). Why do I need this keyword in general and in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extern` tells the compiler that the name defined is in another compilation unit.
A global function definition is `extern` by default. So that covers why it worked in your case.

A place where you'd **have** to use it, is when defining and declaraing global variables.

If there is a global variable that a compilation unit needs to be aware off (say a mutex), you need to make it available in said unit. But if you do this:

```
int a; // in global scope
```

The compiler will try to allocate memory for it in the programs static memory and will give a redifinition error. `extern` comes to our rescue here. By writing:

```
extern int a;
```

We are providing a declaration for the global, but not allocating memory for it.

But since such use of globals is discouraged, you'd rarely see it in use.

Comment: But it works even I defined this functions as static in class (not global function). What compiler do in this case? Why I don't need extern?

Comment: @user14416 The tutorial doesn't say you *need* to use extern, it just shows you one way to do it which does use extern. You have found a different way without using extern. That's OK. Dima has a good explanation above of what extern does, except that he doesn't seem to realise that you are declaring a global variable not a global function.

Comment: @user14416, C++ overloads the use of `static` quite a bit.
Defining a method as static **within a class** is not the same as defining a gloal static method. In the former case `static` means the method is a class method and doesn't have an implicit `this` pointer, while in the latter in means the method his hidden in the compilation unit.

Comment: @john, yeah, I got a bit carried away to point out the typo in code example of the question...